# if $E,F$, two bases are orthonormal then $T$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $T:V\to V$ and two bases of $V$: $E = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ and
>   $F = \{T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_n)\}$.
>
> Prove: $E,F$ are orthonormal implies $T$ is unitary.

So basically we want to prove that for every $v\in V$:$$TT^*(v) = 1_v \iff TT^*(v)-1_v(v) = 0 \iff (TT^*-1_v)(v)$$

First of all, it's a well-known fact that $TT^*-1_v$ is conjugate to itself. If we proved that for every $v\in V$: $$\langle TT^*(v)-1_v(v), v\rangle = 0 $$

It would imply that $TT^*-1_v \equiv 0$ and we're done.

So I'm stuck at this point (not sure if even this is the right/optimial way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can restate this relationship
$$\langle TT^*(v)-1_v(v), v\rangle = 0$$
as
$$\langle Tv, Tv\rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$$
using linearity and the definition of the adjoint.

Expressing the vector $v$ in terms of the given orthonormal basis $e_i$ we see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle Tv, Tv\rangle &=& \langle T\sum v_i e_i, T\sum v_j e_j\rangle \\
&=& \langle \sum v_i T(e_i), \sum v_j T(e_j)\rangle \\
&=& \sum v_i\sum \overline{v_j}\langle  T(e_i),  T(e_j)\rangle \\
&=& \sum v_i\sum \overline{v_j}\delta_{ij} \\
&=& \langle v, v \rangle \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Shouldn't it be (3rd line): $$\sum v_i\sum \overline{v_j}\langle  T(e_i),  T(e_j)\rangle$$

Comment: @jmiller  Yes, it should be.  Updated.

Comment: So basically it's $$\sum v_i\overline v_i = \sum \left|v_i\right|^2 = \|v\| \ne \langle v, v\rangle$$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @jmiller   $\sum |v_i|^2 = ||v||^2 = \langle v, v \rangle$

Comment: Oh right right... Thanks!